# Prove that $f(x,y) = 1/(x^2 + y^2)$ has limit $\infty$at $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

The question is: "prove that function $f(x,y) = $ $1 \over (x^2 + y^2)$ have limit $\infty$ in point $[0,0]$.

This is pretty standard question, and even my book answers it immediately afterwards, but it answer begins with "A is any number from $\mathbb R$, let's assume that $\delta = $ $1 \over \sqrt (2|A|)$, so it doesn't give me any strategy to look for the right $\delta$, except for "lucky guess". How do I find $\delta$ here without first guessing it and than proving that my guess was indeed right?

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 2):

To reach a useful guess, note that, for every positive $\delta$, $$\|(x,y)-(0,0)\|\leqslant\delta,\ (x,y)\ne(0,0)\implies f(x,y)\geqslant\frac1{\delta^2}.$$

Comment: Maybe $f(x,y) \ge $$1 \over 2\delta^2$?

Comment: Why the half? $ $